# Every jvm created for each application, is this a thread or a process

Tags: java, multithreading, process, jvm

A new JVM instance is allocated to every application that user start using jre. Does this JVM a new process or thread ? and Why ?

Answer (score 4):

> Does this JVM a new process or thread ?

A process.

> Why?

a) Because that is that way that "modern" operating systems work ...

b) Because if JVMs were threads (within a larger process) then different JVMs would be able to interfere with each other ways that would be impossible to entirely control.

c) Because attempting to address b) would be difficult and would most likely have significant performance implications.

Comment: Does this means two jvms in a system shares nothing? Not even metaspace(string pool, class data)?

Comment: That is more or less correct.  (They may share code segments from the Java executable and shared (native) libraries.)

Answer (score 1):

If JVM is a thread, then how JVM can manage all this I/O control, thread control and controlling the application run under JVM (who should start JVM?). 
Threads don't have separate address space, run in a shared memory space. Threads are designed for doing small tasks and loading it with heavy task leads to an unhanded situation (from OS perspective). Threads can communicate easily whereas IPC is quite resource intensive. We are installing software everyday, we are creating process.

Answer (score 0):

JVM is equivalent to an Operating System process.JVM is Java Virtual Machine.it is a memory space where classes are loaded and objects are shared. 
It is a process....

Comment: Instead of saying that a JVM is _equivalent to_ a process, say that it _runs in_ a process.